# Gaussian Curvature 2

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\varphi(u,v)=(u,v,h(u,v))$ a parametrization of graph $\Gamma_h$ of $h:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ . Show that the Gaussian curvature can be expressed as $K(u,v)=\dfrac{\text{det}(Hess(h))}{(1+\|\nabla h\|^2)^2}$, where $Hess(h)$ is the Hessian matrix.

Hello, can someone help me with this problem? Thanks.

Comment: how do you originally defined the Gauss Curvature?

Comment: Hello, Gaussian curvature is defined as $K(p)=k_1(p)k_2(p).$ You can help me with this problem?

Comment: yes i could but I need to see how much do you understand the frame ideas... so what are the $k_1,k_2$ for you?